# Use data points from table to generate an untirupted line pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have this figure:

[image]

The continuous line is the gauss function plotted. I want to replace the function with my data points (which is the the red-dotted line) and look the same. Meaning having a continuous line, and be filled with color underneath. Unfortunately, I do not know how to do that. Can anyone help? (sorry for posting again, I have tried to figure this out on my own, but did not work) Thank you!

My code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{datax.dat}
x,y
-1.9,0.001
-1.8,0.001
-1.7,0.002
-1.6,0.001
-1.5,0.01
-1.4,0.004
-1.3,0.005
-1.2,0.008
-1.1,0.01
-1,0.014
-0.9,0.029
-0.8,0.037
-0.7,0.056
-0.6,0.119
-0.5,0.187
-0.4,0.391
-0.3,0.667
-0.2,1.062
-0.1,1.648
0,2.418
0.1,2.454
0.2,1.829
0.3,1.243
0.4,0.809
0.5,0.537
0.6,0.319
0.7,0.178
0.8,0.101
0.9,0.06
1,0.035
1.1,0.019
1.2,0.018
1.3,0.014
1.4,0.019
1.5,0.004
1.6,0.004
1.7,0.002
1.8,0.003
1.9,0.001
2,0.003
2.1,0.001
2.2,0.002
2.3,0.001
2.4,0.001
\end{filecontents}


\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}


    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{
        /pgf/declare function={
            % normal distribution where \mean = mean and \stddev = sd}
            gauss(\mean,\stddev) = 1/sqrt(2*pi*\stddev^2) * exp(-((\x-\mean)^2)/(2*\stddev^2));
            % define xmin and xmax only once here and reuse them later
            xmin=-2;
            xmax=2;
        },
    }

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=middle,
        axis on top,
        xmin=xmin,
        xmax=xmax,
        domain=xmin:xmax,
        samples=100,
    ]
        \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:xmin,0) -- (axis cs:xmax,0);

        \addplot [
            thick,
            name path=table,
        ] {gauss(0.1, 0.25)};
        \addplot table [
        x index=0,
        y index=1,
        col sep=comma,
        name path=table
        ] {datax.dat};
        % instead of using a function here you could also give table values or read a (table) file
       % \addplot table {<table> or <file name>};

        \addplot [
            fill=red!10,
        ] fill between [
            of=axis and table,
        ];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I think the only thing that is wrong is that you add `name path` to the options of the table, not the plot. Use `\addplot[name path=table] table [
        x index=0,
        y index=1,
        col sep=comma,        
        ] {datax.dat};` instead. And there is absolutely no need to apologize for posting questions.

Comment: @marmot It worked perfectly. It seems a bit weird to me that it works like that... To get this right, the table contains only the information about the data points, therefore, the name of the path must always be added to the plot. 

The table is only "importing" the data values, right?

Again, thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Yes, that's right. In the options of the table you should add information which column contains the `x` coordinates and so on. I added an official answer which I will be happy to remove if you feel it is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I have accepted your answer as the correct one!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you add name path to the options of the table, not the plot. These are options that affect the plot, and not the table, and hence should be added to the plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{datax.dat}
x,y
-1.9,0.001
-1.8,0.001
-1.7,0.002
-1.6,0.001
-1.5,0.01
-1.4,0.004
-1.3,0.005
-1.2,0.008
-1.1,0.01
-1,0.014
-0.9,0.029
-0.8,0.037
-0.7,0.056
-0.6,0.119
-0.5,0.187
-0.4,0.391
-0.3,0.667
-0.2,1.062
-0.1,1.648
0,2.418
0.1,2.454
0.2,1.829
0.3,1.243
0.4,0.809
0.5,0.537
0.6,0.319
0.7,0.178
0.8,0.101
0.9,0.06
1,0.035
1.1,0.019
1.2,0.018
1.3,0.014
1.4,0.019
1.5,0.004
1.6,0.004
1.7,0.002
1.8,0.003
1.9,0.001
2,0.003
2.1,0.001
2.2,0.002
2.3,0.001
2.4,0.001
\end{filecontents}


\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}


    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \pgfplotsset{
        /pgf/declare function={
            % normal distribution where \mean = mean and \stddev = sd}
            gauss(\mean,\stddev) = 1/sqrt(2*pi*\stddev^2) * exp(-((\x-\mean)^2)/(2*\stddev^2));
            % define xmin and xmax only once here and reuse them later
            xmin=-2;
            xmax=2;
        },
    }

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        axis x line=bottom,
        axis y line=middle,
        axis on top,
        xmin=xmin,
        xmax=xmax,
        domain=xmin:xmax,
        samples=100,
    ]
        \path[name path=axis] (axis cs:xmin,0) -- (axis cs:xmax,0);

        \addplot [
            thick,
            %name path=table,
        ] {gauss(0.1, 0.25)};
        \addplot[name path=table,mark=square*,color=red] table [
        x index=0,
        y index=1,
        col sep=comma,        
        ] {datax.dat};
        % instead of using a function here you could also give table values or read a (table) file
       % \addplot table {<table> or <file name>};

        \addplot [
            fill=red!10,
        ] fill between [
            of=axis and table,
        ];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]